# Laravel single request multi API handler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm currently working on a project and i would like to implement a single request multi API handler

This is a sample request http://localhost:8000/api/v1/apis?products&outlets&registers

I have a route apis that would loop through each input request key then check if there's an existing api routes matching to the request the dispatch capture the response then push to an array. But it is not working.

```
Route::get('apis', function(Request $request) {
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $responses = [];
    $i=0;
    foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
        $request = Request::create('/api/v1/' . $key);

        try {
            $routes = Route::getRoutes();
            $routes->match($request);

            $response = Route::dispatch($request);

            $responses[$key] = $response;
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $responses[$key] = [];
        }
    }

    return $responses;
});
```

This is the response i'm getting

```
{
    "products": {
        "headers": {},
        "exception": null
    },
    "outlets": {
        "headers": {},
        "exception": null
    },
    "registers": {
        "headers": {},
        "exception": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code make it works

```
$responses[$key] = json_decode($response->content());
```